# ZF2 - Updating fields in an entity

Tags: orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I currently have the following database structure:

```
table: user
fields: user_id, name, id
```

The following entity I got from a tutorial and it works perfectly:

```
<?php
    namespace Administration\Entity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /** @ORM\Entity */

    class User {
        /**
         * @ORM\id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        protected $id;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name") */
        protected $name;

        public function setName($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        public function getName() {
            return $this->name;
        }
    }
```

The problem however is that I want to use the field: user_id instead of id and thus update my entity to the following to use the new field name:

```
<?php
    namespace Administration\Entity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /** @ORM\Entity */

    class User {
        /**
         * @ORM\user_id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        protected $user_id;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name") */
        protected $name;

        public function setName($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        public function getName() {
            return $this->name;
        }
    }
```

This now gives the following error:

```
 Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException' with message '[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\user_id" in property Administration\Entity\User::$user_id does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.' in /trunk/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php on line 52
```

Clearly the error is stating that the user_id property does not exist, but I do not understand why this is the case.

When I delete the field and re-add it I get the same error

If I add id as the primary field and user_id as another field in the entity, it does not throw an error.

Is it possible that all primary fields should be called id and ZF2 expects this??

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, basically the @ORM\Id identifies the primary key and not the field name: id...

This is what was a little confusing.